# How do you filter Algolia Results and omit a specific objectID

Tags: algolia

I'm trying to filter algolia results and want to use the name of a product to find similar products in our database.  I would prefer to ignore the current product so, in the case no results are found, the `removeWordsIfNoResults` option will be used.

I'm using the Ruby api.

This is basically what I'm trying but it is not working.  Is it possible to filter out a specific objectID?

```
Product.raw_search("Men's Bridge & Burn Camden Steel Blue", 
  { :hitsPerPage => 10, 
    :page => 0, 
    :attributesToRetrieve => "objectID", 
    :filters => "objectID != '65411'", 
    :removeWordsIfNoResults => 'lastWords' 
  }
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`objectID` is a specific attribute in Algolia that is always a string value and cannot be added to the `attributesForFaceting`  .
However, if you're filling it with the ids you have in your database, you can index another attribute (let's say `id`) with the same value.

#### Numerical value

As an numerical value, you can directly filter on it using Algolia. However, since you'll only be using the `!=` operator, I recommend you to declare it in the [`numericAttributesToIndex`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-numericAttributesToIndex) list with an `equalOnly` modifier:

```
index.set_settings({
  numericAttributesToIndex: %w(equalOnly(id))
})
```

At query time, you can pass it as you did in your example if you remove the quotes around the value:

```
index.raw_search('Product title', {
  filters: 'id!=65411'
  # Your other parameters
})
```

#### String value

With a string value, you want to add it to your [`attributesForFaceting`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-attributesForFaceting) :

```
index.set_settings({
  attributesForFaceting: %w(id)
})
```

Then query it like so:

```
index.raw_search('Product title', {
  filters: 'id:-65411'
  # Your other parameters
})
```

(The `-` for exclusion is described in the [`facetFilters` documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-facetFilters))

Comment: This sounds great.  I'll try it out

Comment: Worked like a charm.  One note - adding `numericAttributesToIndex` seemed to remove the implicit numericAttributesToIndex that were created by default. I added them back explicitly